# Combining Explain and Union

Tags: mysql, union, explain

Morning all,
I'm trying to quickly compare multiple queries that do similar tasks and I'm wondering if there's a quicker way of lining up the EXPLAIN outputs. To me, this example query should work:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) AS thetotal, date(datetimefield) AS theday, key_id FROM dbname.tablename WHERE datetimefield >= "2015-12-12 00:00:00" AND datetimefield <= "2015-12-12 23:59:59" GROUP BY key_id UNION
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) AS thetotal, date(datetimefield) AS theday, key_id FROM dbname.tablename WHERE DATE(datetimefield) = "2015-12-12" GROUP BY key_id, theday;
```

and output something like the following:

[image: Two rows of explain select output]

but as you probably know it gives a "Syntax error, unexpected describe" message. Is there any reason why it shouldn't, or a way to achieve a similar result? At the moment I'm running EXPLAIN on the two similar queries, exporting them to csv, opening both in a spreadsheet editor and pasting them one row after the other.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can give me.

Comment: Is the command line an option? If so, you could do basically what you described quickly with `mysql -u -p -Bse"EXPLAIN" >> file.txt` twice.

Comment: UNION can only combine two SELECTs, EXPLAIN is not a SELECT even when it seems to just return rows.

Comment: Thanks @WAF, command line definitely an option. If you want to make that an answer I'll choose it.

Comment: The first `SELECT` is much better than the second if you have `INDEX(datetimefield)`.  This is because the second hides the index column inside a function (`DATE`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jkavalik said in a comment, according to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) `UNION` can only be used to combine the outputs of `SELECT`s, which `EXPLAIN` is not.

However, you can line up the raw outputs of each `EXPLAIN` in a text file using the MySQL commands in a shell. Run this once for each EXPLAIN statement:

`mysql -u $USERNAME -p$PASSWORD -Bse "[EXPLAIN STATEMENT GOES HERE]" >> explains.csv`

From the MySQL docs:

> -B: Print results using tab as the column separator
>
> -s: Silent mode. Produce less output.
>
> -e *statement*: Execute the statement and quit.

This will give you a tab delimited row and `>>` will append to the file specified at the end, creating it if it is not already there.